# Adding a carriage return to window.location email call

Tags: javascript, email, newline

I am trying to code a quick function that prompts the user for their email (after clicking "forgot password" and inserting that in the email (as per my bosses' request) *roll eyes*

here is what I have but the "\n" escape does not translate to the body of the email and it all prints into one line.  I would like to have the email appear on a line below the generic text.  Is this even doable?

Before you ask, no I don't have access to the HTML code for the site, so it has to be a js call, because that's what I have control over...

```
function onForgotPasswordID() {
    var email = prompt("Please enter the username for the account:")
    var restString = 'mailto:DataGenAnalytics@HANYS.org?subject=Password Change Request&body=I forgot my password please send me a temporary password. \n Email: ' + email;
    window.location = restString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, literally new line characters are most likely not allowed. You should use:

```
window.location = restString.replace('\n', escape('\n'));
```

Comment: meh, none worked.   It may not  be something I can do...The escape(restString) give me a bad link error.

Comment: @Darw1n34 try it now

Answer (score 1):

Use `%0D%0A` instead of `\n` (URL encoded newline)

```
var restString = 'mailto:DataGenAnalytics@HANYS.org?subject=Password Change Request&body=I forgot my password please send me a temporary password.%0D%0AEmail: ' + email;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use URL encoding.

Line Feed is represented by %0A

Carriage Return is represented by %0D